# pandas complex filter by content in other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the next

```
category, start, end
c1, 100,200
c1, 101, 180 <- this one should be deleted since it is contained in the prev
c2, 10,40
c2, 35, 45 <- c2 should both be kept 
c3, 50,100
c3, 60,100 <- again, deleted
```

So the result should be

```
category, start, end
c1, 100,200
c2, 10,40
c2, 35, 45
c3, 50,100
```

I need to filter nested elements (nested means: elements are as one-dimentional vectors, so start and end are inside the range of another element) with the same category while keeping the larger. Since these dataframes have a length of about 100000, it is taking a while with my current approach.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    #filter all that are nested into this
    res = df[(df.category == row.category) & (df.start >= row.start) & (df.end <= row.end) & (df.index != idx) ]
    l.append(res)
res = pd.concat(l)
#remove all nested
df.drop(res.index,inplace=True)
```

In each step of the loop, it takes all nested elements of the current element and add it to a list of dataframes, after that it drops all those elements.

Can you think of a better approach to this?

Comment: Could you share a snippet of your dataset, to show how the nesting works?

Comment: actually I just add elements in the dataframe, like [cat, start, end], and sometimes elements are inside one another according to these values

Comment: I think I understand. So they're not actually nested python objects (eg a nested list), it just happens that some start / end times overlap?

Comment: A small example of the data would still be helpful if you're able to.

Comment: yes, we can only guess without data sample

Comment: @tworec is the added example ok?

Comment: In your `c2` same input, should the output contain one row like `c2,10,45`, or must it contain both of the original rows instead?

Comment: @JohnZwinck should keep only originals

Comment: What if there are `c2,10,14` and `c2,13,17` and `c2,14,20`?  Which ones should be kept then?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the first is not nested in any of the other two so it should be kept, the second however is nested on the third, so it should be removed. 1 and 3 should be kept.

Comment: I don't understand: [13,17] is not nested in [14,20] according to your definition of nested, so you should keep all three, but you say you only want to keep two.  Why?

Comment: @JohnZwinck you're right, keep three of them.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is cross join by column `category`:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df1, on='category')
m = ((df1.start_x >= df1.start_y) & (df1.end_x <= df1.end_y) & (df1.index_x != df1.index_y))
idx = df1.loc[m, 'index_x']
print (df.drop(idx))
  category  start  end
0       c1    100  200
2       c2     10   40
3       c2     35   45
4       c3     50  100
```

Comment: Clever. I still can't understand how it works from reading it, but trust you :)

Comment: @Phil Sheard- Thank you, but in my opinion always the best is test each solution it carefully ;)

Comment: I just ran a demo on some dummy data, I understand now. `pd.merge` is doing an outer join on `category`, so you end up with each entry being compared with every other possible entry. I guess that a large dataset with only a small number of categories would get exponentially large? As each row is compared with a large number of potential candidates.

Comment: @PhilSheard - yes, exactly. In large data it should be big df, you are right. al depends of number unique categories and their sizes.

Comment: well I tested this solution and with small datasets it works perfectly, but with largers the script gets killed, I imagine because of lack of memory (I'm running in a 32GB machine but 100's of thousands of entries)

Comment: @user1532587 - I was worried about it :(

Comment: @user1532587: Are you willing and able to use Numba?  We could certainly make a faster solution using that...but only if you are able to install it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - thank you, but I have no experience with numba.

Comment: I like the subtlety of dropping any idx which appears to be nested at least once. Keeping the idx that has a nested record wouldn't work in this case.